# How can I import CSS in CSS with file path for AdminLTE theme?

Tags: php, css

I have the following three files located in the `dist/css` folder

```
AdminLTE.css
AdminLTE.min.css
fonts.css
```

Using theme AdminLTE, `fonts.googleapis.com` goes on Google wants on local so firstly following the procedure like [fonts.googleapis.com wants on local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235673/fonts-googleapis-com-wants-on-local/45236032#45236032) fonts.css want to import in adminlte.css and adminlte.min.css

Example:

```
@import url("fonts.css");
```

Is that correct way to import CSS in CSS in same folder? All files in same directory.

Comment: Why would you import a `css` in another `css`? I mean you can just link both on the html/php page.

Comment: Why don’t you just _test_ this yourself …?

Comment: Why you need `url()` just rewrite it this way: `@import "fonts.css`

Comment: It's very unclear what it is you are asking here. I have tried to improve the grammar of your question but the English is just to broken to properly understand it. I would recommend planning what question you would like to ask in your native language and maybe using some translation service such as http://translate.google.com to convert to English. Without better explaining what you want to achieve and why, this question is likely to get few good answers and may even be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly link the CSS in your head section of your page like

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/AdminLTE.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/fonts.css">
```

before this **copy and past** `dist` folder from **AdminLTE** to your root folder of your project. this will work. Please try.

Comment: i want import css in css

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
@import 'fonts.css';
```

instead of this,

```
@import url("fonts.css");
```